# two subgroups of $S_{n}$ and $S_{m}$

Tags: group-theory

If $H\subseteq S_{n}$ and $K\subseteq S_{m}$ how can I then show that I can think of $H\times K$ as it was a subgroup of $S_{m+n}$?

Comment: Let $S_n$ act on $\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$ and $S_m$ on $\{n+1,n+2,\ldots,n+m\}$.

Comment: What? I don't see how this could help me. Can you do a reference to a theorem?

Comment: I doubt that a reference would be the best thing. 
Remember that when acted upon by permutation numbers are just labels/name-tags. The symmetric groups of $\{1,2,3\}$, $\{A,B,C\}$, $\{apple,orange,banana\}$ are all isomorphic to $S_3$. Let's look at an example with $n=3, m=4$, $H=\langle(123)\rangle$ and $K=\langle(1324)\rangle$. Then $1+3=4, 3+3=6, 2+3=5$ and $4+3=7$, so we form a subgroup of $S_7$ that isomorphic to $H\times K$ by using the generators $(123)$ and $(4657)$.

Comment: I think it's also important to know that [disjoint permutations commute](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Disjoint_Permutations_Commute), to see why this works.

Comment: Or for a different way of getting the same end result: conjugate $K$ within $S_{n+m}$  with the product of the $2$-cycles $(1,n+1)$, $(2,n+2)$,$\ldots$, $(m,n+m)$. But let $H$ be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In hopes of getting this off the Unanswered list, here’s a hint expanding on Jyrki’s first comment.

$K$ is a group of permutations of the set $\{1,\dots,m\}$, so each $k\in K$ is a bijection $$k:\{1,\dots,m\}\to\{1,\dots,m\}\;.$$ For each $k\in K$ let $$\hat k:\{n+1,\dots,n+m\}\to\{n+1,\dots,n+m\}:n+i\mapsto n+k(i)\;,$$ and let $\widehat K=\{\hat k:k\in K\}$.

> Show that $\widehat K$ is a group of permutations of $\{n+1,\dots,n+m\}$ and is isomorphic to $K$.

For each $\langle h,k\rangle\in H\times K$ let $$g_{\langle h,k\rangle}:S_{n+m}\to S_{n+m}:i\mapsto\begin{cases}
h(i),&\text{if }1\le i\le n\\
\hat k(i),&\text{if }n+1\le i\le n+m\;,
\end{cases}$$

and let $G=\{g_{\langle h,k\rangle}:\langle h,k\rangle\in H\times K\}$.

> Show that $G$ is a subgroup of $S_{n+m}$ and is isomorphic to $H\times K$.